Trying to prove item 2 of problem 8.8 of haim brezis
Hi I tried to prove the number 2 in problem 8.8 Brezis, this stament is the following:

Let $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Show that if $u(0)=0$, then $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in L^p(0,1)$ and
$$
\left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1}\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} .
$$
[Hint: Use Problem 34, part C.]
Conversely, assume that $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$ and that $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in$ $L^p(0,1)$. Show that $u(0)=0$.
[Hint: Argue by contradiction.]

I saw the following inequality in the previous item:
$$
\left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \left\|\frac{u(0)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} + \left\|\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x u'(t) \, dt \right\|_{L^p(0,1)}.
$$
but I don't know how to conclude the number 2, if $u(0) = c \neq 0$ only I see that in this case $$\left\|\frac{u(0)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} = \infty$$ but how to relate with $\left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)}$ any idea?

see the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491952/brezis-probem-8-8?rq=1

@daw yes, but I don't understand why ?   $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in L^p(0,1)$ if and only if $\frac{u(0)}{x} \in L^p(0,1)$ how to prove the  the return?

you can use the equation (1) of that answer to get an upper bound of $| u(0)/x|_{L^p}$.
